# Как привязать ширину кнопки к параметру "ширина колонки"?

Tags: java, gui, javafx

Как можно привязать  ширину кнопки (`Button`) к ширине определенной колонки в таблице (`TableView`)? Смысл в том, чтобы при увеличении ширины колонки, ширина кнопки тоже увеличивалась на это же значение. Читал про binding и property, но не получилось связать два параметра вместе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button.prefWidthProperty().bind(column.widthProperty().multiply(1));
```

Берем кнопку, берем у нее свойство, которое отвечает за предполагаемую ширину, связываем со свойством ширины колонки и умножаем на коэффициент, в данном случае на 1, чтобы у нас ширина кнопки была равна ширине колонки

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Всё сработало как надо. Чётко , коротко и по делу. Спасибо.